# Can I remove this closet?

Tags: walls, load-bearing

I have a closet in the middle of my house on the first floor I would like to get rid of. I am concerned it could be load bearing since it is in the middle of the house. But there isn't only that closet there is also a half-bath. I am removing just the closet and keep the half bath where it is.

In my picture the part I wanna remove is marked in red. I have also attached more pics to give you fuller ideas of the layout.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The odds of that being load bearing are _probably_ pretty small, **however**: What's above that closet? Obviously, there's a 2nd floor up there - is the space above the middle of a bedroom or is a bathroom/laundry room (where those closet walls could also be hiding plumbing)? What about the rafters above the 2nd floor - which way do they run?

Comment: I am removing only the "exterior" wall of the closet, meaning the common wall to the half bath will remain. there is no baths above that, there is the hallway. on the second floor

Comment: (1) Is there a basement or crawl space? If so, please take a picture of the area under the closet showing any framing and foundation. (2) Is there an attic?  If so, please take a picture of the framing (joists/rafters) above the closet. And as FreeMan asks, what is right above the closet? Walls that align? Can you tell which way the ceiling joists run on this floor?

Comment: there is no basement. there is slab directly under the tile, also it is the first floor of 2 so there is no attic view 
There is a hallway above the closet. I can't tell the way the joists run unless I open the celling drywall

Comment: You can often glimpse the framing by removing a vent cover or light fixture. Peek around the edge with a good light to see the joists. You can probably see which direction the ductwork runs from the ceiling vents without removing the covers. Generally between joists.

Comment: @HABO good tip, but even if it runs perpendicularly does it mean that all perpendicular walls are load bearing? I would think no

Comment: Most short walls are usually not load bearing, unless extra weight in that section or those few joists needed support because of splicing there(very unusual).

Comment: I believe if it's slab and not foundation it can't be load bearing. I am not sure this is *always* true, so perhaps others can chime in. This means that if the wall's bottom plate is flush with the floor, it's on slab and thus not load bearing. If there are a few inches of foundation above the slab under the bottom plate then it's load bearing. Cutting a bit of drywall / baseboard at the bottom should reveal the answer.

Comment: @P2000 just  to make sure I understand, you are  saying load bearing walls have a couple of inches of elevation above  foundation? Also when I say slab I mean house foundation. In Texas most  houses' foundation is just  slab.

Comment: Ok if it's all slab foundation, then I'm not sure. But in my region, where the ground freezes, load bearing walls cannot sit on slab, they need footing and foundation. They usually stick out a few inches above the slab because the slab is poured after the foundation. In your case, maybe the best test is to cut out a few inspection holes to see if joists terminate at the walls or brace them.

Comment: oh yeah in Texas  all  walls are just sitting on slab no matter load bearing or not. So I am thinking already of cutting some holes  or maybe trying through the vents as some suggested.

Comment: @Rainmaker  monolithic slab foundation has footings under load bearing walls too. There is extra thickness in these areas.

Comment: @Kris but that's under (or in) the slab, leaving no hints of it at the wall. Would there be anchors maybe?

Comment: @P2000  correct    Just pointing out that load bearing walls are not just sitting on the slabs

Answer (score 3):

The walls themselves are probably not load-bearing but there may be a post that supports a beam or a beam junction.
The best way to proceed is to hire an engineer before making such a substantial alteration. My bet is, there is sooner a post than a whole wall that bears the load. And, if I wanted to do further homework before hiring a professional, I would look at the orientation of the joists. The walls that are parallel to your joists are unlikely to be load-bearing. Ones that are perpendicular, may be. Both of those wall types may be hiding a post inside. To determine joist direction, remove one of the two ceiling air returns or vents you have there and you will likely reveal the joists. This will save you making unnecessary holes in the wall at this point.

One important heads-up:
I just did a renovation in my house where I opened up a kitchen and living room and I am talking from my experience. I ended up leaving the post in a small wall that I left alone and the plan still looks very open, however, leaving the post was the least of my problems.

The walls I removed were full of electric wiring, HVAC ducts, and even a natural gas pipe. Luckily there was no water plumbing as it would have complicated things even more. It is likely that the builders used these walls as an easy way to route all these things between the levels of your house.

As you confirm the "demolitability" of that wall, be prepared to plan for possibly routing electric, HVAC, and other things that can complicate things immensely depending on how much you are willing to demolish in the process. In my case, I had to run a few new cables all the way from the basement, as the existing wire wouldn't reach to where I wanted it and I would no longer have a room for Jbox either. I had to reroute HVAC ducts under the floor and above the ceiling (in the attic space). If you have access to look under your floor and above the ceiling, you will gain a better understanding of what you are dealing with.

I don't mean to discourage you, it maybe completely DIY-doable (I did and I had no prior experience in the project as involved as this), and you may have a very easy case. Just be prepared for these things as you plan. Ask a lot of questions here before you assume and after your own research. If you think through and plan well, you will likely come up with some creative ways to go around obstacles and still stay to the code. Folks here are amazing and I couldn't have done all this that easily if I hadn't had their help (thanks folks!)

Here is a before-after of the things I had to deal with in just ONE wall.
[image]

Here is another where non-load-bearing wall concealed a load-bearing post, as well as ducts.
[image]

Comment: your results look great! I think that post is not a problem at all. I can see why there was a bunch of stuff in that wall since it was the side of the stove

Comment: Thanks, Gas wasn't too bad, as I simply opened up the floor, capped it off and also have access to it from the basement. I switched to induction and that made dealing with routing gas a non-issue. I did have to run a big-ass 50A 240V line from the basement though, that as unrolling made an unfortunate recoil couple of times to my groin :). Electricians probably know what I am talking about. The worst part was the HVAC as it's SO big and I had to cut the subfloor and the ceiling, had to crawl in a limited attic space. Luckily I was also demolishing entire tile floor so that wasnt in the way.

Comment: Yes, determine orientation of joists, and cut some holes to look for joist ends and any beams. I think even an engineer would need that.

Comment: @Rainmaker are these skylights or shop lights above your island?

Comment: shop lights, I am planning to get rid  of them so I can cut holes and see what in between stories but they are a bit further from the closet

Comment: @Rainmaker I asked for two reasons, if they were skylights, your joists would run parallel,. If they are shop lights, why don't you take one down, make a hole in there if there is not one already, or look in the possible existing hole, you should be able to see the joist. Even better, you have that huge air return in the ceiling, it is likely using the joist space as a return, or at the very least there is a duct. Remove the cover and you will see without question how the joists run. No need to make holes just for that.

Comment: yeah those are shop lights and I am planning to get rid of them anyways so I will be able to determine the direction of joists.

Comment: @Rainmaker see my suggestion about removing the hvac vent cover instead to reveal the joists. Removing the two screws should do it.

Comment: yeah I got it, usually vent cover goes straight to the duct. Meaning you can't see the joists just straight the inner lining of the duct itself. Otherwise if there Is space between the vent  and the duct the cool air will be lost and the system will not work as expected.

Comment: @Rainmaker True, but if the duct is fed in the ceiling between the joists from the exterior wall (which often is the case), you will see that by looking under the cover.